# Converting from Google spreadsheet to excel - standard deviation

Tags: excel, google-sheets, excel-formula, excel-2010

I have this formula in a google spreadsheet `=STDEV(ARRAYFORMULA(IF(I22:NI22>0,I22:NI22)))/1440`
which correctly calculates the standard deviation of the data within those cells.

However, once I export the spreadsheet into excel and move some of the cells around I get `=IFERROR(STDEV(IF(I9:NI9>0,I9:NI9))/1440, "no data")` as a formula. However, the result of this is always "no data". Breaking it down further: `=IF(I9:NI9>0,I9:NI9)` returns "#VALUE!" with the error "A value used in the formula is of the wrong data type".

What would be the correct way of converting this formula from Google spreadsheets to Excel.

P.S. I'm not sure if it matters but I use excel 2010

Comment: Did you remember to commit it as an array formula in Excel, i.e. using CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER? I'm not sure if exporting between the two versions automatically does this for you? Or perhaps you edited the formula after exporting and weren't aware that it needed re-committing as an array formula?

Comment: Just to re-inforce XOR LX's comment - this is the correct formula, you just need to "array enter" it

Comment: THANKS! I didn't know that was a shortcut. I had tried putting in the braces myself but it never worked.

Answer (score 0):

The reason it says "A value used in the formula is of the wrong data type", is because you asked if an array > 0, while Excel was excpecting just values. Try to save the copied data from Google Spreadsheets as an array, or perhaps something like `STDEV(IF(COUNTIFS(I9:NI9, "<>"&0,I9:NI9, "<>"))/1440` might help you.